# How to redirect user to requested url after login? (LoginRequiredMixin Django)

Tags: django

I don't know how to properly redirect user. I've tried so many solutions from the internet that I can't remember them now coz of my frustration. These solutions use def views but I have class views in my app and I don't know how to get this next parameter.

I have a class view which requires login:

```
class EditSportFieldView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    login_url = "/sign-in/"
    (...)
```

I am at the url http://127.0.0.1:8000/sign-in/?next=/sport-field/edit/1/ and after login in I want to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/sport-field/edit/1/ but instead I go back to the main page http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Here is my sigin in view class:

```
class SignInView(LoginView):
    template_name = "sign-in.html"
    redirect_field_name = "sign-in"

    # def get_success_url(self):
    #     return ("/")

    def get_redirect_url(self):
        redirect_to = self.request.POST.get(
            self.redirect_field_name, self.request.GET.get(self.redirect_field_name, "")
        )
        return redirect_to
```

Why I am such a noob? and how to solve it please?

P.S. erros change so fast that I missed that now this redirection takes me to Page not found http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/profile/

Comment: If you're using the built-in `LoginView`, why don't you just change the `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings? Alternatively just pass the redirect login in the template as per [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView)

Comment: Because I am a newbie in Django and I overlooked this simple solution while trying to find missing code in my views and forms.
And after figuring out other errors by myself, I was overwhelmed at this point and wanted to get help from others. Thank you.